# Ajax issue : Parsing JSON Request failed

Tags: php, json, ajax

I've an issue with my code. I would like to send an email but it doesn't works ...
I'm searching since 2 days and I don't found the issue !

Thank you very much in advance for your help !

The HTML form :

```
<div id="contact">
    <form action="#" method="post">

                <div id="contact-input">
                 <!--[if IE]>
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                <![endif]-->
                  <input type="text" name="contact[name]" id="name" placeholder="Name (required)" >
                   <!--[if IE]>
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <![endif]-->
                  <input type="text" name="contact[email]" id="email" placeholder="Email (required)">
                   <!--[if IE]>
                        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                    <![endif]-->
                  <input type="text" name="contact[subject]" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" >
                </div>
                <div id="contact-textarea">
                 <!--[if IE]>
                        <label for="message">Your Message Here</label>
                    <![endif]-->
                  <textarea name="contact[message]" id="message" cols="39" rows="4" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div id="contact-submit">
                  <div>
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Post Comment" class="comment-submit small button">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
</div>
```

The Ajax request :

```
$("#contact form").submit(function()
{
    var form = $(this);
    var formParams = form.serialize();
    console.log(formParams);
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'contact.php',
        type: 'POST',
//traditional: true,
        data: formParams,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log("success");
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);              
            if(response.success)
            {   
                console.log("win");
                $('#contact form').slideUp().height('0');
                $('#contact .result').append(mailSuccess);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("lose");
               for(i=0; i<response.errors.length; i++){
                 if(response.errors[i].error == 'empty_name'){                          
                   mailResult.append(nameError);
                 }
                 if(response.errors[i].error == 'empty_email'){                          
                   mailResult.append(emailError);
                 }
                 if(response.errors[i].error == 'empty_subject'){                          
                   mailResult.append(subjectError);
                 }
                 if(response.errors[i].error == 'empty_message'){                          
                   mailResult.append(messageError);
                 }
                 if(response.errors[i].error == 'invalid'){
                    mailResult.append(invalidEmailError);
                 }
               }
            }
        },
        error: function(x,e) {
//console.log("AJAX error in request: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            if (x.status==0) {
                console.log('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
            } else if(x.status==404) {
                console.log('Requested URL not found.');
            } else if(x.status==500) {
                console.log('Internel Server Error.');
            } else if(e=='parsererror') {
                console.log('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
            } else if(e=='timeout'){
                console.log('Request Time out.');
            } else {
                console.log('Unknow Error.\n'+x.responseText);
            }
        }

    })
    return false;
});
```

And the PHP code (contact.php) :

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/json');
define('TO_EMAIL', '"Email" <emailadresse@gmail.com>');

class Mailer{

private $_params;
private $_errors;

public function __construct(){
    $this->_params = $this->LoadParams();
    $this->_errors = array();
}

public function run(){  
    if($this->Validate()){
        $res = $this->SendEmail();
        if($res === true)
            $this->OnSuccess();
        else
            $this->OnError();   
    }else
        $this->OnError();       
}

private function LoadParams(){
    ?>
    <script>
        alert('form : ' + <?php print $_POST['contact']; ?>);   
    </script>
<?php
    return $_POST['contact'];
}

private function Validate(){
    if(!(isset($this->_params['name']) && ($this->_params['name'] != '')))
        $this->_errors['name'] = 'empty_name';
    if(!(isset($this->_params['email']) && $this->_params['email'] != ''))
        $this->_errors['email'] = 'empty_email';
    else{
        $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
        if(!preg_match($email_exp,$this->_params['email']))
            $this->_errors['email'] = 'invalid';
    }
    if(!(isset($this->_params['subject']) && $this->_params['subject'] != ''))
        $this->_errors['subject'] = 'empty_subject';
    if(!(isset($this->_params['message']) && $this->_params['message'] != ''))
        $this->_errors['message'] = 'empty_message';

    return (count($this->_errors) == 0);
}

private function SendEmail(){
    $headers = 
        'From: "' . $this->_params['name'] . '" <' . $this->_params['email'] . ">\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: "' . $this->_params['name'] . '" <' . $this->_params['email'] . ">\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $to = TO_EMAIL;       
    return mail($to, $this->_params['subject'], $this->_params['message'], $headers);
}

private function OnSuccess(){        
    echo '{"success": true}';
}

private function OnError(){
    $response = '{';
    $response .= '"success": false, "errors": [';

    foreach($this->_errors as $key => $value) {  
        $response .= "{ \"field\": \"$key\", \"error\": \"$value\"},";
    }
    if(count($this->_errors) > 0)
        $response = substr($response, 0, -1);
    $response .= ']}';

    echo $response;
//        echo json_encode(array("success"=>"false"));
}

}

$mailer = new Mailer();
$mailer->run();

?>
```

Comment: I have no tine to go through your code, but you shouls not use parseJSON method if you already defined the data type to be json. Jquery will parse the data automatically

Comment: To be honest, I don't know why it's not working.
Could we really do : name="contact[message]" / name="contact[subject]" / etc.. and receive datas using $_POST['contact'] ?

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy So I can delete the line :
var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
and use data.success ?

Comment: As a general rule you should construct your response as a PHP variable and use `json_encode` this will minimize the chance of errors due to invalid JSON. And yes, if you specify the correct mime type for the response (and optionally the dataType in the AJAX request) then you don't need to do parse the data because JQuery would have already done that.

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks, I deleted the parseJSON and used data instead of responses.

Comment: @mfvjunior Currently the console send me back this error : Parsing JSON Request failed.

Comment: I switched the JSON code in contact.php

Now, it's : echo json_encode(array("success"=>"true"));
and echo json_encode(array("success"=>"false"));

And there is still the error : Parsing JSON Request failed.

Comment: Can you check the network tab response text to see what you're actually getting?

Comment: @apokryfos The response given by the POST request is the whole code of contact.php ...

<?php
header('Content-type: text/json');
define('TO_EMAIL', '"Email" <emailadresse@gmail.com>');

class Mailer{

private $_params;
private $_errors;
etc....

Comment: @LacroixAlexis seems like your server isn't running your PHP code. Make sure you have PHP installed and added to the list of your server's handlers.

Comment: @apokryfos Hum it's not my server. I'll check with the owner to resolve this issue. Thank you ! I'll come back to you when PHP is installed (if he's currently not)